# Build a table one column at a time

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to build a table in MySQL using multiple fields from different tables, but some of the tables have multiple keyed valued (this is a wordpress database) and there's too many datapoints to run it with a single query. Trying to figure out how to fill in the first three columns, then use those values to fill in the next few columns, etc.

`

```
INSERT INTO order_output(order_id, order_item_id, customer_id)
SELECT p.ID, wcoi.order_item_id, pm1.meta_value FROM wp_posts p
LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items wcoi
    ON p.ID = wcoi.order_id
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm1
    ON p.ID = pm1.post_id AND pm1.meta_key = '_customer_user'
WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_order' and p.post_status = 'wc-processing';
```

`

This works fine and fills in the first three columns of the table. But then when I try to run

`INSERT INTO order_output(email) SELECT u.user_email FROM wp_users u INNER JOIN order_output oo ON u.ID = oo.customer_id`

It won't fill in the email column. I've tried a few variations on this, UNION is throwing an error, it will either do nothing at all or just double the size of the table without ever filling in the email column.

Comment: `UNION` will allow you to put multiple SQL queries with the same column definition together, which is not what you're trying to do here. If I understand your requirements correctly, you're going to want to look into using an `OUTER JOIN` or a nested query.

Comment: *It won't fill in the email column.* INSERT query inserts new row. It does not insert a value into the column in existing row. You need in UPDATE query.